# javascript: call base class function

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, extends, prototypal-inheritance

I have the following code, and I am trying to inherit from a base class. Why does the code say that `identify()` is not defined? Shouldn't it call the function from the base class?

> Error: ReferenceError: identify is not defined source1.js:23:9

```
class TestBase {
    constructor() {
        this.type  = "TestBase";
    }

    run() {
        console.log("TestBase Run");
    }

    identify() {
        console.log("Identify:" + this.type);
    }
}

class DerivedBase extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.type  = "DerivedBase";
    }

    run() {
        console.log("DerivedBase Run");
        identify();
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
  let derived = new DerivedBase();
  derived.run();
}
```

Comment: have you tried calling `this.indentify()`?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't work.

Comment: @SinisterMJ `this.identify()` absolutely works. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLwbQp

Comment: Cause it was a copy paste error... indentify() was in his code, and I did not notice the typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `this.identify()` instead.

For more information you can read about [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) in general.

Please take into account that classes in javascript are just a syntactic sugar on top of [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance).

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks! Will accept in a few minutes, doesn't let me yet.

Comment: @Kingsley The conversation is misleading because falinsky edited his answer.

Answer (score 5):

add `this` before call the function `identify()`;

```
run() {
  console.log("DerivedBase Run");
  this.identify();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **identify()** is the function of the class inside which it is defined, therefore if you write `identify()` directly then it will look for `window.identify()` which in our case is not true. So to define the current scope to look for the `identify()` function, we need to mention **this**, which will represent the current class in which i9t is defined.

***Your correct answer is***

```
run() {
  console.log("DerivedBase Run");
  this.identify();
}
```

***Your improved code is as follows:-***

```js
class TestBase {
    constructor() {
        this.type  = "TestBase";
    }

    run() {
        console.log("TestBase Run");
    }

    identify() {
        console.log("Identify:" + this.type);
    }
}

class DerivedBase extends TestBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.type  = "DerivedBase";
    }

    run() {
        console.log("DerivedBase Run");
        this.identify();
    }
}

/*window.onload = function() {
  let derived = new DerivedBase();
  derived.run();
}*/

let derived = new DerivedBase();
derived.run();
```